# Compare and copy two the same option but different in script(C# Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, settings

I have 3 script which is **OptionPopup.cs**,**MC_StreamingOption.cs**,**MC_OptionPopUp.cs**. Now here is a screenshot of my UI so that you can fully understand my question.

[image]
The Option below on the left side the `Horse Racing Scene` must be the same value as on the Game Option Board which is on the right side.

For ex: I choose `Rendering` then on the **GameOption** the `Rendering` also will be checked the same as when i choose on the **GameOption** the `Rendering` then on the Horse Racing Scene below on the left side the `Rendering` will be checked.

So here is my script for the **Game Option**(On the right side option).
Note: *They are on different scenes so basically i could not use static field on my UI's*

## OptionPopUp.cs

```
 public void LiveStreaming()
{
    
    if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME && MC_StreamingOption.isLiveStreamingOutside)
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        isCheckedLivestream = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(LiveStreaming_, 1);

        if (isCheckedLivestream)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Rendering_, 0);
        }
    } else
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        isCheckedLivestream = false;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(LiveStreaming_, 0);

        if (!isCheckedLivestream && render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Rendering_, 1);
        }
    } 
}

public void Rendering()
{

    if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME && MC_StreamingOption.isRenderingOutside)
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        isCheckedRendering = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Rendering_, 1);

        if (isCheckedRendering)
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(LiveStreaming_, 0);
        }
    } else
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        isCheckedRendering = false;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(Rendering_, 0);

        if (!isCheckedRendering && livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(LiveStreaming_, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what i'm doing in the **Horce Racing Scene**(on the left side below)

## MC_StreamingOption

```
//[PK Debug 2/6/2018]
public string RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME = "popup_radiobtn01_on";

public string RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME = "popup_radiobtn01_off";

[SerializeField] UIButton livestream = null;

[SerializeField] UIButton render = null;

public static bool isLiveStreamingOutside = false;
public static bool isRenderingOutside = false;

public void LiveStreaming()
{
    if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        //render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;

        if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_, 1);
            isLiveStreamingOutside = true;
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;

        if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_, 0);
            isLiveStreamingOutside = false;
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
}

public void Rendering()
{
    if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;

        if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.Rendering_,1);
            isRenderingOutside = true;
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    } else
    {
        render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;

        if (render.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.Rendering_, 0);
            isRenderingOutside = false;
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm calling the Game Option(On the right side) by this code:

## MC_OptionPopUp.cs

```
if (tzGlobal.Instance.UserConsoleType == tzGlobal.eGameRH_ConsoleType.LOBBY)
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_) == 1)
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
        else
        {
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(OptionPopup.Rendering_) == 1)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
        else
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
        }
    }
```

Just like that so that you will know that i'm doing it like that. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out with my problem.

Comment: I always have a script that doesnt inherit from monobehaviour that has static fields accesible in the whole game (between scenes)

Comment: how did you do that sir?

Comment: @NoobProgrammer What he means is that if the script inherits from MonoBehavior `(class MC_StreamingOption : MonoBehavior)` It will be destroyed if you load another scene. You have several options here, one is to add a method `DontDestroyOnLoad()` with parameter: the GameObject that your script is attached to. Another option is to remove the `: MonoBehavior` up top where the class is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did here is this

```
if (livestream.normalSprite == RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME)
    {
        isLiveStreamingOutside = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_, 1);

        if (isLiveStreamingOutside)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(OptionPopup.Rendering_, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {

        isLiveStreamingOutside = false;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(OptionPopup.LiveStreaming_, 0);

        if (!isLiveStreamingOutside)
        {
            render.normalSprite = RADIO_ON_SPRITE_NAME;
            livestream.normalSprite = RADIO_OFF_SPRITE_NAME;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(OptionPopup.Rendering_, 1);
        }
    }
```

So from **MC_StreamingOption.cs** I have no choice but to get the playerprefs again. And it works.